# JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale Local 0x31 (should be 0x39)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Good day. Wrote code that should set key values.

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_example_woodman_testlibsettingsv2_frmMain_SetSystemKeysString(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jstring key_Name_) { 
    const char *key_Name = env->GetStringUTFChars(key_Name_, 0);

    // TODO

    jclass secClass = env->FindClass("android/provider/Settings$System");
    jmethodID secMid = env->GetStaticMethodID(secClass, "putString", "(Landroid/content/ContentResolver;Landroid/net/Uri;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z");

    jclass activityThread = env->FindClass("android/app/ActivityThread");
    jmethodID currentActivityThread = env->GetStaticMethodID(activityThread, "currentActivityThread", "()Landroid/app/ActivityThread;");
    jobject at = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(activityThread, currentActivityThread);
    jmethodID getApplication = env->GetMethodID(activityThread, "getApplication", "()Landroid/app/Application;");
    jobject context = env->CallObjectMethod(at, getApplication);

    jclass c_context = env->FindClass("android/content/Context");
    jmethodID m_get_content_resolver = env->GetMethodID(c_context, "getContentResolver", "()Landroid/content/ContentResolver;");
    jobject o_content_resolver;
    o_content_resolver = env->CallObjectMethod(context, m_get_content_resolver);

    jstring jStringParam = env->NewStringUTF(key_Name);
    jboolean jStringKey = env->CallStaticBooleanMethod(secClass, secMid, o_content_resolver, jStringParam, env->NewStringUTF("1"));

    env->DeleteLocalRef(jStringParam);

    return jStringKey;
}
```

But when I try to execute, I get an error.

```
E/stlibsettingsv: JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale Local 0x31 (should be 0x39)
A/stlibsettingsv: java_vm_ext.cc:542] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted local reference 0x31
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]     from boolean com.example.woodman.testlibsettingsv2.frmMain.SetSystemKeysString(java.lang.String)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
A/stlibsettingsv: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x7968c450 self=0x74e3014c00
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | sysTid=32691 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7568948548
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | state=R schedstat=( 316288736 11800419 156 ) utm=29 stm=2 core=5 HZ=100
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | stack=0x7fe34db000-0x7fe34dd000 stackSize=8MB
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #00 pc 00000000003c26c0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+220)
```

Can everybody have a problem?

I read a lot of forums and websites. There is no solution anywhere.
Thanks.

Add:
This line causes an error.

```
jboolean jStringKey = env->CallStaticBooleanMethod(secClass, secMid, o_content_resolver, jStringParam, env->NewStringUTF("1"));
```

All the rest work out correctly. The problem with calling the putString method.

Comment: There's not enough information in the question. For example, which line of code triggers the crash? Where is `key_Name_` assigned its value, and where it that reference deleted?

Comment: This code looks strange, you don't release `key_Name` but `DeleteLocalRef(jStringParam)` makes no sense. Nevermind. Use ndk-stack to find the line that causes the crash.

Comment: @AlexCohn added an explanation to the post

Comment: You do zero error checking, so you have no idea what fails first.  Likely one of your `findClass()` or `getStaticMethodId()` calls fails, or one of your `Call*Method()` calls throws an exception, but since you never check, you don't know.

Comment: If you comment out `env->DeleteLocalRef(jStringParam)`, does it still crash the same way?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I already wrote where the problem is. exactly which place. and just ask to say how to call this method correctly. The problem is that I do not know how to call it correctly. you start to invent ... problem in calling the method putString. via CallStaticBooleanMethod

Comment: @AlexCohn where does this line? I wrote where the problem is and on which line.

Comment: On the face of it, the ine `jboolean jStringKey = env->CallStaticBooleanMethod(secClass, secMid, o_content_resolver, jStringParam, env->NewStringUTF("1"));
` looks OK. This means that some subtle thing went wrong. To find this subtle thing, you must modify your code and see how this effects the results. Another good step would be to print all the parameters to logcat.

Comment: I guess that you know that the problem is on this line because when you remove it, the crash goes away. But this is not enough to understand why the crash happens.

Comment: *I already wrote where the problem is. exactly which place. and just ask to say how to call this method correctly. ...* Your comment demonstrates a lack of understanding about the consequences of failing to check for errors when making JNI calls.  An error such as you're seeing can be caused by failing to identify and properly handle an earlier error.  JNI code can and will fail in unpredictable ways when errors are ignored.  You have not demonstrated that **every** call prior to the one that creates a visible error is free from problems. You **can't** know it's OK if don't check for errors.

Comment: @AlexCohn the problem is exactly how to pass parameters in putString method. with getString figured out. but with putString not working yet

Comment: @AndrewHenle Good. Now I will try to make a code to display information in logcat

Comment: `key_Name_` is already an type of `jstring`, so `const char *key_Name = env->GetStringUTFChars(key_Name_, 0);` is useless, you can just replace the `jStringParam` from this line `jboolean jStringKey = env->CallStaticBooleanMethod(secClass, secMid, o_content_resolver, jStringParam, env->NewStringUTF("1"));` with `key_Name_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit of the failure is this line:

```
jmethodID secMid = env->GetStaticMethodID(secClass, "putString", "(Landroid/content/ContentResolver;Landroid/net/Uri;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z");
```

You are trying to find the static method ID of

```
protected static boolean putString(ContentResolver resolver, Uri uri, String name, String value)
```

for class `android.provider.Settings$System`, but this class does not have such a method at all.

Although, we know

```
public static final class System extends NameValueTable {
    ...
}
```

But, this is a static method of class **`NameValueTable`** which **CANNOT** be inherited by **`System`** class.

So, you need change the method signature to below:

```
jmethodID secMid = env->GetStaticMethodID(secClass, "putString", "(Landroid/content/ContentResolver;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z");
```

Note that the `;Landroid/net/Uri` is removed from your method signature.

Comment: Thank! It helped!

Comment: @Алексей Still think I'm inventing problems?  Hopefully you'll learn from this.